# GVim crashes when opened by clicking

Tags: upgrade, vim, latex

I have been a user of GVim for many years now. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04. I recall during the upgrade that it asked me if I wanted to keep my .vimrc file, I said yes (because why the hell not).

Anyway, the problem is, I can now open any text with GVim from a terminal, but if I open my home folder (without the terminal) and go and try to open a text file ending in .tex with GVim, it crashes right after opening. I checked with many file types : the only ones causing the crash are .tex files (for those who might not know, these are TeX files used by pdflatex for creating beautiful PDF files, among other things).

Where should I start looking to fix this crash, or has any other TeX user experienced it after upgrading? I tried re-installing vim (sudo apt remove --purge vim, sudo apt install vim) but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Did you have any tex/latex vim plugins installed (which might not be compatible with the upgrade?)

Comment: The only plugin I can think of would be LaTeX-Suite. But it works fine when I open the same file from the terminal (and the plugin works as well)

Comment: Then perhaps the gvim .desktop file isn't invoking gvim in the same way? or is invoking a different version of the program?

Comment: @steeldriver : How would I tell? By the way, see my edit~: I reinstalled vim and the problem still occurs.

Comment: Does this occur with all file managers, or just Nautilus?

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver : I can't reproduce the problem anymore, and this happened on a computer I don't have anymore. But I remember that I only used Nautilus.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Hm. Seeing as it would be difficult to make progress or help others with a similar problem, have you considered closing or deleting the question?